# probability - What is the distribution of this descrete random variable?

Tags: probability

We have $N$ balls in the bag, numbered from $1$ to $N$. we pop balls with no returning them to the bag.
let $X$ be "the number of the ball that we poped first", andy $Y$ is the second ball that we poped.
So, i understand that $X\:~\:U\left(1,N\right)$, but i don't get what is the distribution of $Y$, because its realy depends on $X$. I saw somewhere that it also $Y\:~\:U\left(1,N\right)$ but i dont understand why..can someone prove me? tnx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $Y$ can take up $N-1$ possible values.

$P(Y=y)=\sum_{x=1}^NP(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x)$

Now $X\in U(1,N)$ hence $P(X=x)=\dfrac{1}{N}$ for all $x\in\{1,2,...,N\}$. Note that in the above sentence in finding $P(Y=y)$ the component $P(Y=y|X=y)P(X=y)=0$ as you are considering Without Replacement sampling. So there are $N-1$ terms in the sum on the R.H.S.

Now given that we know which ball has been already popped, there are $N-1$ choices for $Y$.

$\therefore P(Y=y)=P(Y=1|X=x)P(X=x)+...+P(Y=y|X=x-1)P(X=x-1)+P(Y=y|X=x+1)P(X=x+1)+...+P(Y=y|X=n)P(X=n)=\dfrac{1}{N}(\dfrac{1}{N-1}+\dfrac{1}{N-1}+...+\dfrac{1}{N-1})=\dfrac{1}{N}$

Thus, $Y\in U(1,N)$.